# facebook omniauth login invalid_credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I'm using devise(3.4.1) and omniauth-facebook(4.0.0) (omniauth-oauth2 is at 1.3.1). I've whitelisted my servers on my app. I can sign up from local. But on my staging or production, I keep getting invalid credential error. Logs:

```
I, [2017-09-23T16:07:41.020163 #28378]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2017-09-23T16:07:41.288616 #28378] ERROR -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, :
{"access_token":"EAAMc0KQg6xYBAI1MeVyW5uP3ox4LArwCRKnrvFRoHJl7LhEx5E1P3vtxHLMSGgdlxLTfGlLnckVJP3XLYeZAus0ZAr6H3IIR0UPwMFFoo9MGocN1bZBiB31M4ZCJNGqd6aze1ZCqLn1yZCCkBgO4m37w8FYmrZAg20ZD","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5104141}
```

This happens for both http and https callback urls. I've found one post with the same problem, but the cause there is using older gem (pre-4.0), but I'm already at 4.0. Any help would be much appreciated.